# Use Regex in new Outlook rule

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, regex

Hi is there a way to use a regex wildcard in an Outlook rule, I simply want to skip part of the subject, eg I want to detect `Invoice #12345 from MyMSP Technologies` in the subject but for any invoice number. I'm hoping there's a way to do this with an `*` in place of the invoice number or the like and without writing a VBA script. I'm not finding anything in my search for this. Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks.

[image: Create outlook rule]

Comment: Have you tried using `Invoice from MyMSP Technologies`?

Comment: Yes, didn't work unfortunately.